# DBSCAN for clustering data by location and density

Tags: r, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan

I'm using the method **dbscan::dbscan** in order to cluster my data by location and density.

My data looks like this:

```
str(data)
'data.frame': 4872 obs. of 3 variables:
 $ price    : num ...
 $ lat      : num ...
 $ lng      : num ...
```

Now I'm using following code:

```
EPS = 7
cluster.dbscan <- dbscan(data, eps = EPS, minPts = 30, borderPoints = T, 
search = "kdtree")
plot(lat ~ lng, data = data, col = cluster.dbscan$cluster + 1L, pch = 20)
```

but the result isn't satisfying at all, the point's aren't really clustered.

[image]

I would like to have the clusters nicely defined, something like this:
[image]

I also tried to use use a decision tree classifier **tree:tree** which works better, but I can't tell if it is really a good classification.

**File:**

http://www.file-upload.net/download-11246655/file.csv.html

**Question:**

- is it possible to achieve what I want?
- am I using the right method?
- should I play more with the parameters? if yes, with which?

Comment: You should provide the data set if possible, or a toy data set.

Comment: @lukeA I just added the dataset.

Comment: I don't think the data in the file represents you data set. Please have a look.

Comment: @lukeA: yes, you're right. I mistakenly added the `lng` column twice. I updated the file. I don't know why the extra column `X` appears.

Comment: Thanks. The price attribute is not used? Well, if you want to cluster by location and density, dbscan would be a good choice. It puts together dense parts, e.g. `plot(lat ~ lng, data = data, col = dbscan(data[, c("lat", "lng")], eps = 0.004, minPts = 3)$cluster + 1L, pch = 20)`. However, your ellipses suggest that you want to cluster dense and non-dense parts together. I don't see how this could work. A decision tree would be good for a supervised classification task, but your data is not labled. Maybe someone has an idea. Otherwise I'd try my luck on http://stats.stackexchange.com, too.

Comment: What you sketched are **not density based clusters**. So if that is what you want, you will need a different algorithm (but from what you sketched, I'd say it is statistically not reasonable but rather random.

Comment: @lukeA I used the price in the decision tree classification algorithm. After putting some thoughts in what I need, I realized that I need to cluster by location and price and not location and density.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the output of a careful **density-based clustering** using the quite new HDBSCAN* algorithm.

Using Haversine distance, instead of Euclidean!

It identified some 50-something regions that are **substantially more dense than their surroundings**. In this figure, some clusters look as if they had only 3 elements, but they do have many more.

[image]

The outermost area, these are the **noise** points that do not belong to any cluster at all!

(Parameters used: `-verbose -dbc.in file.csv -parser.labelIndices 0,1 -algorithm clustering.hierarchical.extraction.HDBSCANHierarchyExtraction -algorithm SLINKHDBSCANLinearMemory -algorithm.distancefunction geo.LatLngDistanceFunction -hdbscan.minPts 20 -hdbscan.minclsize 20`)

OPTICS is another density-based algorithm, here is a result:

[image]

Again, we have a "noise" area with red dots are **not dense at all**.

Parameters used: `-verbose -dbc.in file.csv -parser.labelIndices 0,1 -algorithm clustering.optics.OPTICSXi -opticsxi.xi 0.1 -algorithm.distancefunction geo.LatLngDistanceFunction -optics.minpts 25`

The OPTICS plot for this data set looks like this:

[image]

You can see there are many **small valleys** that correspond to clusters. But there is no "large" structure here.

You probably were looking for a result like this:

[image]

But in fact, this is a **meaningless** and rather *random* way of breaking the data into large chunks. Sure, it minimizes variance; but it does not at all care about the *structure* of the data. **Points within one cluster will frequently have less in common than points in different clusters.** Just look at the points at the border between the red, orange, and violet clusters.

Last but not least, the oldtimers: hierarchical clustering with complete linkage:

[image]

and the dendrogram:

[image]

(Parameters used: `-verbose -dbc.in file.csv -parser.labelIndices 0,1 -algorithm clustering.hierarchical.extraction.SimplifiedHierarchyExtraction -algorithm AnderbergHierarchicalClustering -algorithm.distancefunction geo.LatLngDistanceFunction -hierarchical.linkage CompleteLinkageMethod -hdbscan.minclsize 50`)

Not too bad. Complete linkage works on such data rather well, too. But you could merge or split any of these clusters.

Comment: thank you very much for your response and explanation. The `hierarchical clustering` is the closest one to what I wanted. I've put some thoughts and what I need is creating clusters upon location and price. 
The result of the `hierarchical clustering` is very plausible for me.

Comment: Could you tell us with what implementation you have produced those results? Is that implemented in `r` ?

Comment: I used ELKI for these plots, because it supports Haversine distance very well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I tried the parameters you used, in the ELKI GUI and it worked perfectly, but when using it directly in Java, it returns a single cluster.

Comment: The Java API is tricky to use, because of default values. There are so many parameters in ELKI, and the MiniGUI and command line interfaces do a good job at setting all the defaults. If possible, I use a shell script and the command line interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something called as [Hullplot](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dbscan/versions/1.0-0/topics/hullplot)
In your cases

`hullplot(select(data, lng, lat), cluster.dbscan$cluster)`